# What is Pumping length for Union of Regular languages?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

This is an exam question.

For E = {a,b}. let us consider the regular language
$L= \{x|x = a^{2+3k} or x=b^{10+12k}, k >= 0\}$

Which one of the following can be a pumping length (the constant guaranteed by the pumping lemma) for L?

A)3

B)9

C)5

D)24

Ans is 24.

As per me pumping length is the length which gets actually repeated.
So, basically it's the length of y as per pumping lemma [statement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

Now, for the first regular language, $a^{2+3k}$
How I visualized?

There would be sure 2 states which accept min 2 'a' ( since k>=0).

Now, then I have $a^{3k}$
Means, which should definitely have a loop of length 3.

So, I choose x=2 (first 2 states) y=3 (the repeating part) and z=0.

So this first language must have atleast 3 as the pumping length.

And in similar lines the other must have. Atleast 12 as pumping length.
(X=10, y=12, z=0)

And that's why as per me 24 is right.
(Still sketchy at concluding)

Plz tell me if my understanding of Pumping length is right?
If no plz try suggesting some links/references.
If yes then have I applied the Concept right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [pumping length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Formal_statement) is a positive integer $p$ such that any string of $L$ of length at least $p$ can be decomposed in the form $xyz$ with $|xy|\leq p$, $|y|>0$ and for all $n\geq0$ the words $xy^nz$ are in $L$.

Assume that $p<12$. Then the word $b^{10+12}$ should be able to be decomposed as above. We cannot take $y$ with $1\leq|y|\leq p <12$. Otherwise $xz=xy^0z$ wouldn't be in $L$.

We can take $p=12$ or larger.

If $10+12k=|b^{10+12k}|\geq p\geq 12$ then $k\geq1$ and we can decompose $b^{10+12k}$ as $xyz$, with $x=\epsilon$, $y=b^{12}$ and $z=b^{10+12(k-1)}$. Then $|xy|=12\leq p$ and for all $n\geq0$ we have $xy^nz=b^0b^{12n}b^{10+12(k-1)}=b^{10+12(n+k-1)}$ in $L$, since $n+k-1\geq k-1\geq0$

If $2+3k=|a^{2+3k}|\geq p\geq 12$, then $k\geq4$. We can decompose $a^{2+3k}$ as $xyz$ with $x=\epsilon$, $y=a^3$ and $z=a^{2+3(k-1)}$. We have that $|xy|=3\leq p=12$, $|y|=3\geq1$ and for all $n\geq0$ we have $xy^nz=a^0a^{3n}a^{2+3(k-1)}=a^{2+3(n+k-1)}$ in $L$, since $n+k-1\geq k-1\geq0$.

So, the minimum pumping length of $L$ seems to be $12$. Any larger value would also work in this case.

Comment: So you mean to say that pumping length is not y but it's basically the length of the least string that gets accepted by the regular language?

Comment: The least string for a^(2+3k) would be a^5, so is pumping length 5? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: @PiyushSawarkar I meant to say what is written above, which I copied from the linked article, and which seems to be different from what you are saying. The smallest  length of a string in $L$ is $2=|a^{2+3\cdot 0}|$. A pumping length for this language cannot be smaller than $12$ from the argument above.

Comment: Okay so I got my mistake in previous msg, sorry for that. So basically am I right to say that 3k and 12k is the repeating part, and thus we took smartly 10+12k as 12k+10 and then splitted as  12 (bcoz it's the min repeating stuff) and 12+3(k-1) as the rest part.

Comment: And also basically pumping length p is any positive number which can have x and first repeating part of y. For example, in 01*0 the min pumping length will be 01 i.e. 2, am I correct?

Comment: @PiyushSawarkar Yes, your language is defined that way with some words with a part of length $3$ that repeats and some others with a part of length $12$ that repeats. If we want to make $p$ as small as possible, then yes, we would take $x=\epsilon$, the empty word.

Comment: @PiyushSawarkar Yes, for the language consisting of $01*0$, the minimum pumping length is $2$. But sometimes, it is not just about those periods. For example, for the language consisting of the words $01*0$ and the word $55555$, then the minimum pumping length cannot be $2$. It will have to be $6$, such that the word $55555$ is excluded from the requirement of decomposing it in a form that can be pumped.

Comment: Can you plz slightly elaborate that example of 55555, I am getting a bit confused. Do you mean to say that there is a language of containing {01*0,55555} and thus we take pumping length as 6(and why 6 can you clarify that a little bit) sorry if it's too dumb but I am very new to this concept and hardly understood anything..when you gave answer ,now I am feeling a little bit stronger conceptually in this topic.

Comment: @PiyushSawarkar If we take $p<6$ in that other example, then $|55555|=5\geq p$. So, the requirement is that we can decompose $55555=xyz$ with $|y|\geq1$, $|xy|\leq p$ and such that for all $n\geq0$ the word $xy^nz$ is also in the language. But that means that $y$ will contain the character $5$ and therefore, the language would be required to contain words with arbitrarily large number of $5$ in it. But only the word $55555$ contains the character $5$. So, $p<6$ doesn't work as pumping length. Taking $p=6$, works since $55555$ doesn't need to be considered.

Comment: Taking $p=6$, works since $55555$ doesn't need to be considered and you can decompose $01^k0$, for $k\geq3$, as before $x=0, y=1$ and $z=1^{k-1}0$.

Comment: Excellent example, now understood the example thoroughly (although took time!)  Now I am feeling very confident in understanding of Pumping length. Thank you for the beautiful example to illustrate that idea ..!! Also one more trivial question..can you tell me is there any constraint over |x| and |z|..I mean, can they be epsilon both. Yes I do know that |y| should be strictly greater than 1 but what about length of x,z. Plz correct me if wrong..bcoz we said that |xy|<=p and |y|>1 that means |x| can be epsilon. And now what about |z| can that be epsilon too?

Comment: Also in that example when you took 01^k0 there shouldn't the k>=4(so that p=6 ..instead of k being 3)..just had a doubt noticed this now..?

Comment: @PiyushSawarkar Yes, $k\geq4$.

Comment: Okay Thank you!